# Hibernate: Inserting child record with reference to existing parent record

Tags: hibernate

I have a parent and child table. Parent records are already inserted by a different process. I need to add child records that references the PARENT record, for example:

```
PARENT
===========
PARENT_ID   PK
ADDRESS     UNIQUE

CHILD
===========
CHILD_ID   PK
PARENT_ID  FK
ADDRESS    UNIQUE
```

When inserting a CHILD record, the only info I have to reference a parent record is the ADDRESS. I need to fetch the PARENT_ID from the parent table using the child's ADDRESS to set the child's FK.

Is there a way to do this in hibernate such that I don't need to query for parent by ADDRESS to insert it with the child record? Or do I continue down this path where i query for PARENT by ADDRESS then pass the PARENT object to the child?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should definetly read the parent by address and then set that reference into the child and save the child.

Otherwise you would have to use some sort of native query which should always be the last resort, as you will loose the portability of the solution.

You would be left with a native query because the HQL bulk operations (like UPDATE) do not support joins.. neither implicit and neither explicit, and you would need those to perform entire operation in a single query.

Just my opinion, the call is yours.